# How to toggle pin between logic low/high and (moderately high) 14V state?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, circuit-design

I would like to design a programmer for a 27C512 chip. To erase/program this chip, one needs to put 14V on pin A9. While reading from the chip, either 0 or 5V is put on that same pin.

**How to digitally toggle between three voltage levels on a single pin?**

So far, I have designed the circuit below.

- A9IN is connected to a 74HC4040 output pin and is set to GND or to 5V. One of my concerns is that I don't want to fry that chip by putting 14V on one of its output pins.
- A9HIGH is connected to an Arduino output pin. This is how I would like to switch between 14V or use the 0V/5V from A9IN.
- 12V is a voltage source, which can be increased to 14V. (for the sake of this question, feel free to assume it is always at 14V)

[image: Circuit diagram three voltage levels same pin]

Additional notes:
I am very much aware that cheap commercially available programmers are readily available (I have one myself), but this project is mostly a learning experience for me.

Comment: I would simply use a mux like the CD4052B. Do you want to build this from discrete components?

Comment: I have no design requirement that it has to be built from discrete components. Your suggestion is a very good one. I'll be looking into this. Thanks!

Comment: The level at the bases of Q3 and Q5 cannot get higher than about 0,6V because of the base diode of Q3. Did you consider this? -- However, there should be several open hardware projects for EPROM burners in the web. Did you try to find some and look at their circuits?